# Using Python 3 to print out columns of a csv as lists, then use Matplotlib to make a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphing

I'm trying to make a graph from columns in a csv file using matplotlib. So far I have:

```
X = []
Y = []
for line in file:
    column=line.split(',')
    year=str(column[3])
    for year in X:
        X.append(year)
for line in file:
    column=line.split(',')
    emissions=str(column[4])
    for emissions in Y:
        Y.append(emissions)

plt.plot(X,Y)
```

But it is printing out a blank plot.

Comment: Please use the markup features to type in code.  As to your code, you have "for year in X".  There's nothing in X, and there never will be anything in X.  Same with "for emissions in Y".  What did you want to put in X and Y?  Did you perhaps want `X.append(int(column[3]))` and `Y.append(int(column[4]))`?

Comment: What @TimRoberts said is correct. X is empty to start so the `for year in X` is an empty for loop

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use Pandas!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read CSV
df = pd.read_csv('yourcsv.csv')

X = df.iloc[:, 0] # First column
Y = df.iloc[:, 1] # Second column

print('First column: ', list(X), 'Second column: ', list(Y))

plt.plot(X, Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can only read a file once.  After the first loop, you're at the end of the file.  And why would you convert to string when you want integers?  All you need is this:

```
X = []
Y = []
for line in file:
    column=line.split(',')
    X.append(int(column[3]))
    Y.append(int(column[4]))

plt.plot(X,Y)
```